# Filter UIPasteboard when copying web content from safari to contenteditable UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, contenteditable, uipasteboard

My app is a rich editor which uses `UIWebView` and HTML5's `contenteditable` feature.

Now, my app have some problem to deal with copying web content from safari to my UIWebView when the  web content has any image.I want to replace the image html tag `<img>` in the `UIPasteboard` to some of my images.

However, when I using the following code to check the pasteboard, there is **NO** any image in pasteboard. But copy/paste image from safari to my app is working fine.

```
UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
NSLog(@"clip board strings = %@", pasteboard.strings);
NSLog(@"clip board urls = %@", pasteboard.URLs);
NSLog(@"clip board images = %@", pasteboard.images);
```

If I copy some image & text from safari then open my app, the NSLog is below:

```
2012-04-20 14:53:37.558  clip board strings = (
    "text"
)
2012-04-20 14:53:37.559 [46800:17903] clip board urls = (
)
2012-04-20 14:53:37.559 [46800:17903] clip board images = (null)
```

I want to ask, how to get the image info from UIPasteboard and how to manipulate it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the image out of pasteboard using:

```
UIImage *image = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].image;
```

You can check whether pasteboard contains the image file using:

```
BOOL imgPasteBoard= [[pasteboard pasteboardTypes] containsObject:@"public.png"];
```

then by checking the bool value. You can also try using this code

```
[[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] containsPasteboardTypes:UIPasteboardTypeListImage]; UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];  
if (pasteboard.image!= nil) 
{ 
   [self insertImage:pasteboard.image]; 
   //insert image being a function where you write the code to insert Images to psteboard
}
```

hope this helps you..

Now load the UIImage using following code :-

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
[webView loadData:imageData MIMEType:imageMIMEType textEncodingName:nil baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: this seems not work , when i copy a image with text , it just can not get the image

Comment: how to load this UIImage to UIWebview?